# SQL Return distinct values from duplicates where User is not a certain value most of the time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data with duplicate values, I want to return distinct folder values and the 1st User name in the table which isn't the user 'ADMIN', however where the folder is not a duplicate and User = 'ADMIN' I want to return 'ADMIN'.

I've tried using combinations of ROW NUMBER, PARTITION BY and CTEs but can't seem to get the right results.

Example of source data:

```
Folder                          Users
January                         JOHN SMITH
January\Daily                   ADMIN
January\Daily\Sales             ANDREW SMITH
January\Daily\Sales             ADMIN
January\Daily\Sales\Trainers    ADMIN
January\Daily\Sales\Trainers    JAMES MAY
January\Daily\Sales\Trainers    HELEN SMITH
January\Daily\Sales\Jeans       ADMIN
January\Daily\Sales\Jeans       MIKE SMITH
January\Daily\Sales\Jeans       HELEN SMITH
January\Daily\Sales\Jeans       JOHN SMITH
```

Example of Expected Output:

```
Folder                          Users
January                         JOHN SMITH
January\Daily                   ADMIN
January\Daily\Sales             ANDREW SMITH
January\Daily\Sales\Trainers    JAMES MAY
January\Daily\Sales\Jeans       MIKE SMITH
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine the "1st User name in the table"? (i.e. what ordering criteria do you have? As strictly speaking, there is no default ordering in SQL - but I assume you mean in Primary-Key Ascending order?)

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yes you're right there's no order, to be honest I just want the 1st name that appears in the table doesn't matter who apart from cannot be Admin unless there is only 1 folder and Admin is the user, hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I'm using  SQL Server 2014 MS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  a.folder,
  a.users
FROM
(
  SELECT
    folder,
    users,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY folder ORDER BY users) AS row_num
  FROM yourTable WHERE users <> 'ADMIN'
) a
WHERE
  a.row_num = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  folder,
  users
  FROM yourTable WHERE users = 'ADMIN'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t WHERE t.folders = yourTable.folders AND t.<> 'ADMIN');
```

Comment: This does not seem like the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks kc2018, you are an absolute star, works a charm just need to understand it now haha!

Answer (score 2):

There is a question of what "first" means.  Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.

You can do this using

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by folder
                                order by (case when user <> 'Admin' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         ?  -- ordering column
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The idea is simple.  For each folder you are going to choose one row -- hence the `row_number()`.  That row will be the "first" non-Admin row, if any.  Otherwise it is the Admin row.

The `?` is for the ordering column.  You can actually leave it out, and get an arbitrary non-admin row.

Comment: This solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work... assuming you have a suitable `user_primary_key` column for determining the "first" User.

```
SELECT
    Folder,
    FIRST_VALUE( Users ) OVER ( ORDER BY user_primary_key ) AS FirstUserOrAdmin
FROM
    source_data
WHERE
    Users <> 'ADMIN'
GROUP BY
    Folder
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Folder,
    'ADMIN' AS FirstUserOrAdmin
FROM
    source_data
WHERE
    Users = 'ADMIN'
GROUP BY
    Folder
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```